# Smart Thermostat - Boiler does not have a C terminal. Can I use the TV or T instead

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, boiler, smart-switch

I am trying to install an Amazon smart thermostat but the boiler does not have a C terminal.

It has a C1 terminal but I do not think it is the same due to it being connected to the circulator pump (I am assuming too much power). But looking at the schematic there is a B1 that it seems is 24V.

I tested TV to W and T to W and got a reading of 24 volts. I think I can connect the blue wire to either of those. Is that correct?

BTW - I do have central air. Not sure if that gives me other options.

Addition

Thanks!

[image: Boiler Electric Schematic]

[image: Picture of the boiler wiring]

Comment: From your pic is looks to me as though the boiler's `TV` and `W` terminals are connected directly to the transformer. So if the red wire on the `W` terminal is connected to `R` on your thermostat, then `TV` is equivalent to `C`.

Comment: Does that 4-wire cable extending out the top of the aquastat relay go all the way to the thermostat, or does it terminate at some intermediate junction?

Answer (score 2):

I connecting the blue `C` wire to `TV` terminal worked. The smart thermostat is operational. Thank you [@brhans](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/33897/brhans)!

Comment: For future reference: Normally, a "thank you" in an answer is not the way to do it (you'll learn that if you take a few moments to review the [tour]). However, since you posted the actual answer here, and the answer was posted in a comment, this does get a pass. Also, it's nice that you linked to brhans' profile, but that won't actually ping him to let him know you've done so.